# How to Iterate through files in a folder QGIS, using python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, network, iteration

I am using **QGIS 3.16**, and I am trying to run the “**service area from layer**” function on approximately 400 layers (200,000 starting points in total), I am also due to be repeating this at a range of distances so looking to use python. Also, I cannot merge together as there are 1,000s km of road and just not feasible to set it running for next month.

I have been trying to run the “service are from layer” function via python and I can get it to accept my road and node layer, which have to have the same name (but are in different folders), and then output this to a different folder. The issue is that the table contains a row for each service area, but there is no geometry written. Below is the code that I have been working on but reading about I can see that there is something relating to **FeatureSinks** but not sure how I go about including this.

I have tried, but I think my Python skills are just a little too rusty.

My code is below.

```
import os
import processing
import glob
import string

#Folder where my road networks are stored
Select_folderRoads='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/r1/'
#Folder where the starting points/nodes are stored
Select_folderSDH='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/d1/'
#Folder where the output is to be stored
Save_results='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/path250m/'
os.chdir(Select_folderRoads) 

for lyr in glob.glob("*.sqlite"):
        
        #Individual road network layer
        inlayer = Select_folderRoads +lyr
        #Ouptut filename
        outname = Save_results+lyr
        #Layer containing start points/nodes
        startname = Select_folderSDH+lyr
        inlay = lyr[:-7]
        inlayc = inlay.upper()
        
        testinlayer = str(inlayer+'|'+"layername="+inlayc)

        processing.run("native:serviceareafromlayer", 
            {'LAYERS':  inlayer,
            'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,
            'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50.0,
            'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
            'INCLUDE_BOUNDS': False,
            'INPUT': testinlayer,
            'OUTPUT_LINES':outname,
            'START_POINTS':startname,
            'STRATEGY': 0,
            'TOLERANCE': 0.0,
            'TRAVEL_COST': 250.0,
            'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
            'VALUE_BOTH': '',
            'VALUE_FORWARD': ''})
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create a working Python code and I considered that you have many SQLite DBs with just one layer (same name as the DB file in lowercase) in your folders `r1` and `d1`.

Your databases are SQLite DB not spatially aware and I loaded the layers with `ogr` and assign a projection, in your case the OSGB 1936 / British National Grid **EPSG: 27700**, to tell what coordinate reference system (CRS) layers have.

Once QGIS know the projections, it can do the <kbd>Service area</kbd> processing and export geometries.

Here is my working code under QGIS 3.16 (Windows, but I took your question OSX paths for the code below) :

```py
import os
import processing
import glob
import string

#Folder where my road networks are stored
Select_folderRoads='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/r1/'
#Folder where the starting points/nodes are stored
Select_folderSDH='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/d1/'
#Folder where the output is to be stored
Save_results='//Mac/Home/FINAL/March2021/path250m/'
# Set working directory to roads folder
os.chdir(Select_folderRoads)

uk_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700)

# iterate over roads DB network layers
for dbname in glob.glob("*.sqlite"):
    # get layer name from SQLite DB name
    lyr_name = dbname.split(".sqlite")[0].lower()
    # get roads and points layers, set their CRS
    roads_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"{Select_folderRoads}{dbname}|layername={lyr_name}", "roads_lyr", "ogr")
    roads_layer.setCrs(uk_crs)
    points_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"{Select_folderSDH}{dbname}|layername={lyr_name}", "points_lyr", "ogr")
    points_layer.setCrs(uk_crs)

    # processing algorithm that output result as GPKG
    result = processing.run(
        "native:serviceareafromlayer",
        {'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,
        'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50.0,
        'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
        'INCLUDE_BOUNDS': False,
        'INPUT': roads_layer,
        'OUTPUT_LINES': f"{Save_results}{lyr_name}",
        'START_POINTS': points_layer,
        'STRATEGY': 0,
        'TOLERANCE': 0.0,
        'TRAVEL_COST': 250.0,
        'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
        'VALUE_BOTH': '',
        'VALUE_FORWARD': ''}
    )
```